# Why aren't Mapbox vector tiles rendered in the browser?

Tags: tiles, mapnik, mapbox, vector-tiles

Would it be technically possible to have Mapbox's compact vector tile format sent to the client (instead of PNG tiles), then rendered inside the browser with JS code?

Second question: when using TM2/Mapbox Studio, why are the tiles rendered remotely? Couldn't Mapnik be directly used locally to render the tiles? (still using remote data sources like Mapbox Streets)

Comment: Welcome to the site Erik.  Please note that the format here is best suited for one question at a time.  For further details please see http://gis.stackexchange.com/help

Answer (score 2):

> Would it be technically possible to have Mapbox's compact vector tile format sent to the client (instead of PNG tiles), then rendered inside the browser with JS code?

Take a look here:

- https://www.mapbox.com/blog/mapbox-gl/
- https://www.mapbox.com/blog/mapbox-gl-js/

> Second question : when using TM2/Mapbox Studio, why are the tiles rendered remotely?

They are rendered locally, in Mapbox Studio.

Comment: Hi Alex. Thanks for your reply. I'm already aware of Mapbox GL, it's awesome but my question was related to 'classical' vector tiles. 
When you say that the tiles are rendered locally in Mapbox Studio, do you mean by node or by JS on the client side?

Answer (score 0):

> Would it be technically possible to have Mapbox's compact vector tile format sent to the client (instead of PNG tiles), then rendered inside the browser with JS code

That's exactly what [Mapbox-GL-JS](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js) does. [Leaflet.MapboxVectorTile](https://github.com/SpatialServer/Leaflet.MapboxVectorTile) is another option, implemented as a plugin to Leaflet.

> when using TM2/Mapbox Studio, why are the tiles rendered remotely? Couldn't Mapnik be directly used locally to render the tiles? (still using remote data sources like Mapbox Streets)

The Mapbox Studio you're referring to (now "Mapbox Studio Classic") does render tiles locally.