# Highlight polygon on hover and click in TileMill

Tags: javascript, mapbox, cartocss

I have created a MapBox.js map with several layers of polygons each with hover/click interactivity to show attributes about each polygon.  I want the polygons to become highlighted upon a user hover/click with a darker border to help the user identify a polygon.  Something similar to this [example.](http://palewi.re/posts/2012/03/26/leaflet-recipe-hover-events-features-and-polygons/)  What code would I need to add to make this happen? I'm assuming I need to create a CSS file to define the color and size of the outline but I don't know how to make it work with my JavaScript code.  My current source code is [here.](https://github.com/SLUGIS/CalMAPPER/blob/gh-pages/V2.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if you are loading leaflet tile layers, it is not possible to change their style once loaded.

The key difference between your code and the [example code](http://palewi.re/posts/2012/03/26/leaflet-recipe-hover-events-features-and-polygons/) you linked to is that the example code renders geoJSON data directly in the browser.  Notice this line of code:

```
var featureLayer = new L.GeoJSON();
//...
map.addLayer(featureLayer);
```

You are loading you data as a bunch of tile layers, which are pre-rendered .png images, and so can't be restyled in the browser.

With tile layers, all your data is first converted into small png images (either on a server, or locally with something like MapBox's TileMill) for fast load times and nearly no limit on data size; however as a raster source, you lose the ability to manipulate the data itself.

With feature layers loaded from a geojson, you reserve the ability to manipulate your data as a vector--style it in browser, run queries over it, etc--but loading even moderately sized datasets can become an issue.

If you want to be able to restyle your polygons on hover, look at using `L.geoJSON()` or `L.mapbox.featureLayer()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I forgot that the layers are only images and no longer vectors. Maybe it will be possible through vector tiles in MapBox Studio.

Comment: @cbunn check out this SE question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112302/why-arent-mapbox-vector-tiles-rendered-in-the-browser

Comment: Yes, it is possible with MapBox GL, but it's still early in development.  Expect the MapBox GL library to expand a lot; also, there's some talk of expanding leaflet support for vector tiles.